# still for situation of continues

Tags: usage

I would like to inquire about the correct usage of "still". I understood and I am not sure if I am correct, that we use still when an action or situation continues to the present. That means a continuous present tense state. Having said that we should add "ing" to the verb after "still" for example:

```
I still reading the article
```

Do all the verbs after still need "ing" for example which sentence is correct?

```
I still review the article 
I still reviewing the article
```

Comment: You will find illustrated guides to the use of **still** at several sites including: https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/still_1 and https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/still_1

Comment: _Still_ is not a verb, it is an adverb. _I reviewing the article_ is not a grammatical sentence, so _I still reviewing the sentence_ is not a grammatical sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do you have to use the continuous present with "still"?

Commonly you would indeed use the continuous present. For example:

> He is writing. He is *still* writing...
>
> He went for a walk. He is *still* walking.

However, the continuous present is not required. Consider:

> He has been a famous writer for many years. In fact, he still writes.

That's the simple present, used with "still".

Let's consider your example sentences:

> I still reading the article
>   I still reviewing the article

These are not correct, because present continuous should be "am reading" and "am reviewing".

Corrected:

> I am still reading the article
>   I am still reviewing the article

And this sentence...

> I still review the article

...reveals an interesting property of the word "review". If you are reviewing an article, it should be present continuous. "I am reviewing the article". In the simple present, it means "in general" rather than specific. "I review articles" "I still review articles". That means "many articles, in general".  But this is going off on a tangent about how the word "review" works, rather than the word "still".